# mouseup function is not working for iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, mouseup

I want my navigation will slideup when click out side navigaiton/subnavigaion area... I put below code for that. But its not working for iPad. Can anybody help for this?

```
$(document).mouseup(function(){
        $("#navLeft").slideUp(0);
        $("#navRight").slideUp(0);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try on click function?

```
$(document).on('click',function(){
    $("#navLeft").slideUp(0);
    $("#navRight").slideUp(0);
});
```

Comment: Yes.. I have tried it but its not working perfectly... In this case I'm not able to click on links